# i want to write an IF else formula in excel

Tags: excel, if-statement

I want to write an if else formula in excel

**Example**:
for col E i.e Sliderposition

i want a formula stating that if the value of C2-B2< 10 then the slider position should be 1 similarly the slider position should 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 for respective ranges of 10-20 20-30 30-40 40-50 50-60 60-70 70-80

Please revert at the earliest.

Thank you

Comment: Put "excel" and "if" in a search engine. First hit was https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IF-function-69aed7c9-4e8a-4755-a9bc-aa8bbff73be2 . Don't be lazy.

Comment: Am I supposed to **revert** to my horizontal position asleep in bed at the earliest? 8)

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the fact that an expression like `(C2-B2 < 10)` can be used as a number. It is `0` for `FALSE` and `1` for `TRUE`.

Therefore, your formula could be something like:

```
+ (C2 - B2 < 10) * 1 + (C2 - B2 >= 10) * (C2 - B2 <= 20) * 2 + ....
```

If all your level boundaries are equidistant, you could just divide rather than using a complicated statment.

```
+ QUOTIENT(C2 - B2; 10) + 1
```

In case, your border limits are stored in a table, you can use a nifty range lookup trick using `SUMPRODUCT` as explained [here](http://chandoo.org/wp/2010/06/30/range-lookup-excel/).

Comment: combine that summation and you could put that in the lead part of CHOOSE function, which you dont need to do in this case since they really just want the summation as the result.

Comment: CHOOSE just select the nth item of a list of items. How could that help here?

Comment: if he did not want to return 1,2,3,4,5,6 but instead A,bb,c,ddd,e,ff, then you put your summation formula as the first argument of the choose function, and the letter or whatever other results in the subsequent arguments.  BUT, you would have to set your logical arguments so that they add up as you climb the ladder so to speak.  make it so that when logical check 2 is true, then logical check 1 will still be true. etc, or keep it the way it is since it currently returns the value of n for making the nth choice.